# Fix the Screen Size Issue Programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I was creating Android application. that will dynamically create questions. but based on the mobile screen size view is not coming properly. I don't know how to fix this problem. I have enclosed image that is taken form different mobiles.
Screen size -3.7" , Screen Size -5.0"

[image]  [image]

All the Element sizes are varied based on the screen size.can any one help to display responsive screen in Android.

My Code is:

```
lView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
lView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 220);
GradientDrawable gdtitle = new GradientDrawable();

gdtitle.setCornerRadius(5);
ImageView title = new ImageView(Main2Activity.this);
title.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
title.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
title.setBackgroundDrawable(gdtitle);
lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
lView.addView(title);

GradientDrawable gd3 = new GradientDrawable();
gd3.setCornerRadius(30);
gd3.setColor(Color.parseColor("#003366"));
gd3.setStroke(0, 0xFF000000);

TextView uname1 = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
uname1.setText("Hello , "+Sessionname);
uname1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
uname1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#003366"));
uname1.setTextSize(20);
uname1.setLayoutParams(l2);

et1 = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
et1.setHeight(100);
et1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
et1.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
et1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
et1.setHint("Select Date");
et1.setBackgroundDrawable(gd3);
et1.setTextSize(15);
et1.setLayoutParams(l2);

lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams l4 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
l4.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
lHorizontalView1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
lHorizontalView1.setLayoutParams(l4);
lHorizontalView1.addView(uname1);
lHorizontalView1.addView(et1);
lView.addView(lHorizontalView1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're hard-coding your values in pixels. For example for your height you call `setHeight(100)` that means set this `View` to be `100px` tall. However, with different screen densities that's going to look completely different. Given a fix screen size (say 5 inches), one device could have a resolution of `480x800` and another one could be `1440x2560`, your setting of `100px` will look exactly how you have it now.

Use [Display Metrics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) instead to retrieve the screen density and use [device independent pixels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device-independent_pixel) (`dip` or `dp`) instead of pixels (`px`) as units. For example you can set your height based on the density of the device like this:

`setHeight(100 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);`

However, your desired height may have to be smaller as that will become `100dp` so you may have to set it to something like 50 instead. Play around until you get your desired results.

then your `View` will look uniform across devices.